# How to control <iframe> based YouTube player?

Tags: javascript, youtube, html5-video

YouTube allows to use `<iframe>` to embed videos on sites in addition to flash based way of embedding. That has advantages especially for mobile devices.
http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html

Unfortunatly i could not find any API documentation similar to flash based way like http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

Is it possible to control programmatically the `<iframe>` based player using pure JavaScript, for example playing or pausing the video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Operations

> We support a similar set of functions
> for the IFrame API as are currently
> supported for the JavaScript API.
>
> Please refer to that document for a
> list of functions. Please note that
> the functions that deal with video
> bytes behave differently when HTML5
> playback is used via the IFrame API.
> getVideoBytesTotal is hardcoded to
> return 1000. getVideoBytesLoaded will
> return a value between 0 and 1000. To
> calculate the fraction of the video
> that has been loaded you can divide
> the getVideoBytesLoaded value by the
> getVideoBytesTotal value, and that
> calculation will work regardless of
> whether HTML5 or ActionScript 3
> playback is used.

Do note it is a experimental service which should not be used for production level applications.

**Notice**

> Important: This is an experimental
> feature, which means that it might
> change unexpectedly.

Comment: Thenk u, everything worked out nicely. Could you please also give me a hint how to specify wmode=transparent when constructing the iframe player programmatically?

Comment: Probably won't be relevant to OP, but here's an example of how to specify wmode=transparent for any future users `<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/36LVnW3RxQE?wmode=transparent"></iframe>`. [More YouTube player parameters.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)